# How to use synchronized method?

Tags: java, synchronization

I have this piece of code.

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main1 main1 = new Main1();
    Main2 main2 = new Main2();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(main1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(main2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
public class Main1 extends Thread{
    SynchronizedCounter c = new SynchronizedCounter();
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Entering Main1");
        c.print();
        System.out.println("Exiting Main1");
    }
}
public class Main2 extends Thread{
    SynchronizedCounter c = new SynchronizedCounter();
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Entering Main2");
        c.print();
        System.out.println("Exiting Main2");
    }
}
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    public void print() {
        for(int  i = 1; i<10; i++){
            System.out.print(i+ " ");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code , I get different output which I understand why. In order to make it synchronized, I added synchronized keyword to print() in class SynchronizedCounter. 
Now, it looks like this.

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
public synchronized void print() {
    for(int  i = 1; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print(i+ " ");
    }
  }
}
```

But, still , when I run it, I am getting random result.
I am not sure how to make it synchronized by making a method synchronized, so that, it gives a fixed result.

for example :

```
Entering Main1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Exiting Main1
Entering Main2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Exiting Main2
```

Edit : Thanks Kayaman for the answer. It is working fine now. I just changes a little in the code. It looks like this now.

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SynchronizedCounter c = new SynchronizedCounter();
    Main1 main1 = new Main1(c);
    Main2 main2 = new Main2(c);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(main1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(main2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
 }
}

public class Main1 extends Thread{
SynchronizedCounter c;
Main1(SynchronizedCounter counter){
    c = counter;
}
public void run(){
    c.print();
 }
}

public class Main2 extends Thread{
SynchronizedCounter c;
Main2(SynchronizedCounter counter){
    c = counter;
}
public void run(){
    c.print();
 }
}

public class SynchronizedCounter {
public static int i = 0;
public synchronized void print() {
    System.out.println("\n Thread "+ i);
    i++;
    for(int  i = 1; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print(i+ " ");
    }
 }
}
```

Now , the output coming is :

```
 Thread 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 Thread 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: I'm confused. What you are trying to test. What is the current out put ?  There is no point of synchronization here to test.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? At the moment, you have to threads that both write 1-9 on the console. As both are writing to the same console at the same time, the output it quite random.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I guess it's just a learning experience. Actually, if the synchronization works he should get 1-10 in a twice in a row instead of the numbers being mixed - I guess that's what he expects.

Comment: Yes, it is a simple learning exercise :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The threads need to use the same `SynchronizedCounter` instance for synchronization to work. Since you have 2 instances in your code, both threads will be able to synchronize on their own instance and not block.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by others putting `synchronized` on methods synchronizes on the class' instance and since you have 2 you don't actually synchronize both threads.

So depending on your needs, either

- use the same instance of `SynchronizedCounter` in both threads, or
- put the synchronized block inside the method (around the body) and synchronize on the class, i.e. `synchronized(SynchronizedCounter.class) { ... }`

**Edit:**

A comment on your expected output: since you're not synchronizing the `run()` methods of your threads the print statements there, e.g. `System.out.println("Entering Main1");` might still get mixed, i.e. even with the counter being correctly synchronized you still could get something like this (btw there's no linebreak after printing the numbers, I assume you'll add it):

```
 Entering Main2
 Entering Main1
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 Exiting Main2
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 Exiting Main1
```